# Errors from style.xml while using the FAB in Android Studio

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm having "Rendering Errors" from style.xml file. Here is the FAB xml block:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_36dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyFloatingButton"
    app:backgroundTint="#008080"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:rippleColor="#00b3b3" />
```

The style.xml block:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <style name="MyFloatingButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
</style>
```

If I'm making a stupid mistake here, that's because I'm a newbie and this is my first app. I've tried a clean build, didn't help.

Comment: The FAB will take on your app theme style using the primary colors and accents without using the `android:theme` attribute in the FAB XML. Try it with that line removed.

Comment: @DigitalNinja Didn't work. The funny thing is the code broke after I changed the "src" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `style.xml` file, put the `MyFloatingButton` style outside the `AppTheme` style, like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     ...
</style>

<style name="MyFloatingButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```